# Contact Form 7 Selectable Recipients with Pipe - Multiple Emails

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Per Contact Form 7, this code works for sending to one email addresses for each selection. However, what if I need to send to more than one email address for each selection? What would the proper syntax be for sending to multiple email addresses for each selection? I've tested with a comma between email addresses but that does not seem to work. Any other suggestions?

```
[select* email-recipient “Sales|sales@yourdomain.com” 
“Tech Support|support@yourdomain.com” 
“Inquiry|info@yourdomain.com”]
```

Comment: have you tried multiple select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Commas for multiple email id, here is the example,

```
[select* email-recipient "Sales|sales@yourdomain.com" "Tech Support|support@yourdomain.com,test2@yourdomain.com" "Inquiry|info@yourdomain.com,test@yourdomain.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple select option of contact form7 in order to select multiple emails

```
[select* email-recipient multiple "Sales|sales@yourdomain.com" "Tech Support|support@yourdomain.com"]
```